# How to use nano editor for super user (sudo)

Tags: cron

I wonder how to edit crontab with nano editor for super user via sudo. I used the following command but it didn't work. crontab was open but it was not a nano editor.

```
export EDITOR=nano
sudo crontab -e
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `sudo -E crontab -e` to preserve the environment variable `EDITOR` you are setting in your own session.

Comment: Or `sudo EDITOR=nano crontab -e`.